# Find area within set distance from point in a complicated polygon

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math, geometry, polygon

Given a simple (non intersecting) polygon such as a floor plan (with doors between rooms missing so as to give 1 simple uninterrupted boundary). How can I find all areas within the polygon reachable from a (x, y) point (within or on the boundary of the polygon)? I’d ideally like from this to return a polygon which could be then overlaid to show all reachable areas.

I’ve considered A* search type methods where I would search the shortest path iterating over all points located on the polygon perimeter (as destination) then plotting new points at the set distance limit along the shortest path polyline to give a new polygon hull.

I’ve also thought about wave propagation as a method.

I’m wondering if I’m missing something obvious here library/method wise and if anyone has any other ideas of how I might achieve this.

Given a polygon like this:

[image]

I am creating a polygon showing internal space (excluding internal doors) like this:

[image]

This is the part my question refers to. I would like to find all reachable points within the polygon (shown in red as a new polygon) from a given point on the polygon boundary at a set maximum travel distance from that point (donated below with a red square) like this:

[image]

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your first sentence. Can you give an example of what we've got here. Like an example floorplan / the polygon(s) and an example result.

Comment: Please see the updated question for added clarity @Thomas

Comment: Sry, can't give you a solution, just a direction. Take a look at navigation meshes used in games for path finding. Basically a graph of neighboring convex hulls. also take a look at this: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/185828/why-use-convex-polygons-and-not-concave-ones-in-path-finding

Comment: Here are some notes on point-to-point shortest paths: https://graphics.stanford.edu/courses/cs268-09-winter/notes/handout7.pdf . I'd look for a library that implements the Funnel Algorithm since it's not trivial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Triangulate the polygon.

   - If your chosen *origin vertex* is not a polygon vertex (i.e. it's a point within the polygon), include this point as a *steiner point* in the triangulation.
2. Build an undirected weighted graph from the triangulation's vertices and **constrained** edges (where graph edge weights are triangulation edge lengths).

   - Constrained edges are edges that do not lie outside the polygon.
3. Compute shortest paths from your *origin vertex* to all other vertices in the graph (using *Dijkstra* or *Bellman-Ford* algorithm). The path distance from the origin to a vertex is that vertex's *Z* value.
4. Update/create another triangulation mesh, using the same vertices with the *Z* values calculated from before.
5. Calculate distance values for every pixel by interpolating within/between triangles (interpolating based on each triangle's vertices' *Z* values). This is readily done by using [barycentric coordinates](https://codeplea.com/triangular-interpolation). The interpolation output for a coordinate gives you the distance from the origin position to that coordinate.

For the illustrations below I used the [NaturalNeighborInterpolator](https://github.com/gwlucastrig/Tinfour/blob/56f09d55bc46e54583dd404b1a6df348e3378693/core/src/main/java/org/tinfour/interpolation/NaturalNeighborInterpolator.java) from the *TinFour* Java library. It eases the interpolation step by operating on a triangulation — I simply call the interpolator at each pixel coordinate and finally mask the output with the original polygon (since it effectively computes over the convex hull of the polygon).

[image]

[image]

[image] [image]

#### Illustrative Code

The graph and Dijkstra implementation use the *JGraphT* library.

```
IncrementalTin tin = new IncrementalTin();
tin.add(listOfPolygonVertices); // triangulates upon insertion

Graph<Vertex, IQuadEdge> graph = new DefaultUndirectedWeightedGraph<>(IQuadEdge.class);

tin.edges().forEach(e -> {
    if (e.isConstrainedRegionInterior() || e.isConstrainedRegionBorder()) {
        graph.addVertex(e.getA());
        graph.addVertex(e.getB());
        graph.addEdge(e.getA(), e.getB(), e);
        graph.setEdgeWeight(e.getA(), e.getB(), e.getLength());
    }
});

DijkstraShortestPath<Vertex, IQuadEdge> shortestPaths = new DijkstraShortestPath<>(graph);
Vertex originVertex = tin.getNavigator().getNearestVertex(originX, originY);

var paths = shortestPaths.getPaths(originVertex);

IncrementalTin distanceMesh = new IncrementalTin();
for (Vertex v : graph.vertexSet()) {
    var d = paths.getWeight(v);
    distanceMesh.add(new Vertex(v.x, v.y, d)); // add vertices with Z to new tin
}

IInterpolatorOverTin interpolator = new NaturalNeighborInterpolator(distanceMesh);

for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        double z = interpolator.interpolate(x, y, null);
        if (!Double.isNaN(z)) {
            pixels[y * width + x] = someColour;
        }
    }
}
```

#### Update: Distance Boundary Vertices

If you want merely the distance boundary line, you can forgo step 5. Instead, compute (if applicable) the [isoline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_squares#Isolines) for each triangle, based on the desired distance. If an isoline crosses a triangle (as in the illustration below), it will intersect with two of the triangle's edges — plotting a line segment between each pair of intersecting points for every such triangle give you a distance boundary.

[image]

Call a method (such as below) for each edge for every **constrained** triangle in the triangulation. If the distance isoline crosses the triangle, you'll get two points of intersection for that triangle; otherwise none.

```
/**
 * Compute isoline vertex (if applicable) for a triangle side given by two vertices
 */
Vertex isoVertex(Vertex a, Vertex b, double d) {
    Vertex min, max;

    if (a.getZ() > b.getZ()) {
        max = a;
        min = b;
    } else {
        max = b;
        min = a;
    }

    if (d > min.getZ() && d < max.getZ()) {
        double diff = max.getZ() - min.getZ();
        double numerator = d - min.getZ();

        double fract = numerator / diff;
        double xDiff = max.getX() - min.getX();
        double yDiff = max.getY() - min.getY();
        
        return new Vertex(min.getX() + fract * xDiff, min.getY() + fract * yDiff);
    }
    return null;
}
```

[image]

Comment: This looks very promising, thank you. Can it handle holes in a polygon?

Comment: @Ant Yup! Check the new image.

Comment: That’s spot on, thanks for your solution. I’ll check it all out when I get a minute and mark as complete.

Comment: Would it be possible to return a list of points for the coverage polygon (Restricted to the bounds of the original) like in your solid red colour dinosaur example for a set distance from origin? (Rather than pixels inside the distance). I'm nearly there with this. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Ant In that case it might be a good idea to subdivide the triangulation first so you're dealing with smaller triangles (to do this insert points within the constrained shape; poisson disk sampling would generate suitable point distribution set for this). Then, instead of step 5, you basically want to compute a single [isoline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_squares#Isolines) across the triangulation. The isoline will cross a triangle if one of its 3 edges has a value of your given distance (use z values from each pair of vertices to determine if this is the case).

Comment: @Ant To make sure the suggestion wasn't baloney, I've just implemented it myself and have updated the answer.

Comment: thanks that looks rather good. Would I call the isoVertex function instead of distanceMesh.add? I’ve been trying to implement this in google cloud functions as a http callable function from JavaScript, in the original code I seem to be hitting a problem with an error of “graph must contain the source vertex”. I’ll post a new question with my code and link from here.

Comment: Here is the question pertaining to the error I'm getting. I'll integrate your update this weekend but am just wondering if you can see any obvious errors in my code leading to the logged error. Heres the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67215878/error-when-computing-dijkstrashortestpath-in-jgrapht

Comment: Would it be possible to post the full code you have used to generate the update gif and also the the vector array you've used so I can try to replicate. I'm struggling to get it to work at my end.

Comment: @Ant [github](https://github.com/micycle1/DistanceField)

Comment: Thanks for that I’ve managed to get it working. The only issue is that it’s returning some small isolines near the constraint vertices despite them being well above the distance used and much further than the main isoline which looks correct. Have you seen anything like this?

Comment: Ok I've got it fully working now for the iso line. I'm just struggling to include the original polygon perimeter (up to where the isoline intersects it) in the list of lines to form a polygon. Any ideas on that would be really appreciated. Thanks for your help so far. Ant

Comment: It seems that when I try to include these using the constrained region border edges that the odd constraint vertices issue occurs which I mentioned above. Is this a bug in tinfour?